# доступ к классам и методам с другого проекта

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

Есть два проекта. Из одного проекта сделал dll и подключил ее в другом проекте. Но проблема в том, что нету доступа к методам классов.

Проект из которого сделал dll и его классы, методы:

```
public class SettingsDirectory
    {
        public String UpdateServerVersion { get; set; }
        public String UpdateBeginDirectory { get; set; }
        public String UpdateEndDirectory { get; set; }
        public String LocalMainExe { get; set; }

        protected string GetFileXML()
        {
            ...
        }

        public SettingsDirectory LoadFile()
        {
           ...
        }

        public void SaveFile(object obj)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SettingsDirectory settings;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        ...
    }

    private void CheckForUpdates()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void UpdateDirectory(string begin_dir, string end_dir)
    {
        ...
    }
```

В другом проекте подключил Ссылку, using тоже, но доступа нету

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: у вас класс и методы не статические, используйте переменную `settings.SaveFile()`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten понял в чем прикол был, а что, если методы не статические, работать не будет?

Comment: Создайте екземпляр класса и работайте с ним

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я не правильный скрин выложил, с ним и не работало, уже нашел в чем загвоздка была, единственное остался вопрос по поводу статических методов и классов

Comment: все будет работать как часы...вам нужно создать либу...потом подключить е через ссылки проекта + using, и потом юзать. Все что `public` в этой либе вы увидите, как и класс лежащий рядом

Comment: если есть проблема, то вставьте ТОТ скрин, или покажите код с ошибкой

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц не уже разобрался, ну и видимо все методы должны быть пабликом, а у меня есть приватные